# "Side effects", or "Side-effects"?

Tags: hyphenation, popularity

Merriam-Webster implies both are correct:

> side effect (without hyphen)
>
> side-effect (with hyphen)

Which is more common? My go-to litmus test, google searching both and comparing the number of results, does not work here. My specific context here is the body of a medical research paper.

To avoid debates and polling: I'm not asking which is correct (it seems both are acceptable), I'd like to know which is more common.

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=side+effect%2Cside-effect&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) works for this.

Comment: I think that hyphenating "side-effect" only makes sense if you're treating them as a compound noun, such as "We are lowering dosages to reduce the side-effect frequency."

Comment: @BrianDonovan: Hmm, maybe it does and maybe it doesn't. There are possible sentences that contain "side effect" which do not use it the same way "side-effect" is used. The number may be negligible, or it may not, but your assertion that "Ngram works for this" remains, to my mind, unproven.

Comment: @rajah9: I think you're trying to shoe-horn in a completely irrelevant principle. There's actually [no significant usage preference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=side+effect+problems%2Cside-effect+problems&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cside%20effect%20problems%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cside%20-%20effect%20problems%3B%2Cc0) one way or the other with such noun adjunct usages, but Brian's chart looks just the same if you change it to plural (so it *can't* include noun adjunct usages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A great resource open to you for looking at the frequency of words or phrases is **[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/)**.
As Brian Donovan said in the comments, [this Ngrams analysis](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=side+effect%2Cside-effect&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cside%20effect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cside%20-%20effect%3B%2Cc0) answers the question quite well:
[image: Ngrams Screen Capture]

As this shows, *side effect* written as two words has been a lot more common throughout the past half-century with the hyphenated version used much less. That said, the recorded uses of *side-effect* are not negligible, some people do hyphenate.