# "Open source" or "open-source"?

Tags: orthography

Would you say both are correct? I have a doubt about "open-source", but I've seen it quite a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: Please refer [When should compound words be written as one word, with hyphens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spaces)

Comment: See also https://opensource.org/about

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between hyphenated and unhyphenated versions. There are no *stringent rules* for compound words. You can use both versions: **open-source**, and **open source**. They both mean same.

**Further readings:**

[When should compound words be written as one word, with hyphens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spaces)

[Can word-hyphenation ever be semantically significant?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54422/can-word-hyphenation-ever-be-semantically-significant?rq=1)

[“Side effects”, or “Side-effects”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364613/side-effects-or-side-effects?noredirect=1&lq=1)